"nbdev_export Fails When Notebook is Nested Inside a Subfolder within the nbs Folder"
I have a repository where I’ve installed nbdev. Previously, on Linux, I was able to create subfolders inside the nbs directory and successfully run nbdev_export. However, now that I'm using Windows, I encounter an error when trying to use nbdev_export with notebooks inside subfolders. The error message is:

File
"C:\Users\Leni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py",
line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
0)

I’ve found that moving the notebook out of the subfolder, running nbdev_export, and then moving the notebook back resolves the issue temporarily. However, I don’t fully understand why this happens. How can I properly export notebooks that are located in subfolders within the nbs directory?

What's the filepath to the subfolder?

nbs/datasets/water_process
